# Duplicate grub menu in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: grub2, 12.04

I have a problem with my laptop grub menu. duplicate menu appears as below:

> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
>
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
>
> Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
>
> Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic

how to remove duplicates? I use ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: If there is no real "issue" with them, then I'd leave them - have you test all of them to make sure that they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo update-grub` in a terminal. That might help.